# Protecting the AWS S3 download links

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, amazon-s3

I have been developing a website where people can buy digital products and then download them after the payment. I am using MERN stack and thinking of using AWS S3 for storing the digital products.

I am quite worried about implementing the security. I want to make sure that nobody can find an evil way to download files unless they purchased the product.

Not only about AWS S3 but anything you can suggest is appreciated.

I am not really an experienced guy on this industry since I am a mechanical engineer. So, I appreciate even a single bit of your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

It works like this:

- All files in Amazon S3 remain **private**
- Users interact with your website and purchase the software
- Your website then **generates a pre-signed URL**, which is a time-limited link to a private object stored in Amazon S3
- Users can click that link to **download** the file. After the expiry period (which you can set), the link will no longer work.

Yes, they could share that link with other people, but it would only work for the stated time period (eg 5 minutes).

The signed URL only takes a couple of lines of code to generate. It can be generated within your app, without having to make an API call to S3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, I have a couple more questions to ask. The app I am developing allows all the registered users to share their paid/free digital products and there will be a lot of download requests to the server. There will be tons of load as the amount of users grow day by day. So the question is, is your solution still viable in that situation?

Comment: Another thing is, do I have to create 2 buckets, one for paid products and one for free products? If so, the bucket which is for free products should be private as well? But keep that in mind, users can switch their products from paid to free or vice versa.

Comment: Amazon S3 is ideal for high volumes. The great things about pre-signed URLs is that your app does not need to do much work, because S3 does all the file serving for you! It is highly-scaled and can easily handle high loads.

Comment: How do you classify the difference in behaviour for free vs paid products? If 'free' products means they should be accessible to _anyone_ at any time, then it would make sense to put them in a public bucket with no authentication required. If, however, they should always access the files via your app, then you should use pre-signed URLs for _all_ downloads. This allows your app to determine what they are, or are not, permitted to download. It's similar to selling tickets to a concert — your app only has to worry about selling the 'tickets', while S3 runs the concert.

Comment: I am enlightened. It seems I'm going to go for single bucket for all the products and only let registered users to download paid/free products and it's good to know it is scalable. Thank you sir!